# How to add default headerTooltip in ag-grid which is the same value as the data in the cell?

Tags: html, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

As the title says, I am using ag-grid and I want to add default tooltip on every grid in my app. The value of the tooltip should be the same as the value of the cell someone is hovering. I have tried using:

```
this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = {
 tooltip: (params) => {
  return params.value;
 }
};
```

but this doesn't do anything.

I do not want to add it in columnDefs, because then I would have to do it for every single column. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want the tooltip to appear when you hover over a cell, or the column header?

Comment: Sorry, confusing on my part, I want the tooltip to appear when I hover over a cell

Comment: Aswell, if my explanation is bad, it's really similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147736/ag-grid-defaultcoldef-not-re-applied-after-initial-component-load @ViqMontana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `tooltipValueGetter` property and set this in `defaultColDef`  to `params.value`.

```
defaultColDef = {
      tooltipValueGetter: (params) => {
        return params.value;
      }
    };
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2rATUkGEECfWYeIB).

Comment: This will not add default tooltip to header but to the cells

Answer (score 1):

To display a **cell tooltip** with the **same *formatted value* as the cell** by default, use the following grid option :

```
defaultColDef: {
    tooltipValueGetter: function (params) {
        return params.valueFormatted || params.value;
    }
}
```

To display a **header tooltip** with the **same value as the header** by default, unfortunately, there is no option available / no way to set the header tooltip using a function (yet?). Therefore, you have to set it manually for each column definition such as :

```
{
    headerName: "My column",
    headerTooltip: "My column",
}
```